# Preventing script timeout with large jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, nicedit

For the project I'm working on, there are some rich-text editing boxes on the page, the number varies, but can get very large (50+ question/answer sets, each with 8 text boxes).

Originally these were plaintext boxes that accepted HTML, but due to the fact that the end client that will be using this is not fluent in HTML, we changed over to using a richtext editor, so the originals are converted with a javascript richtext plugin (NicEdit).

Due to the variable number of these entry boxes, I'm using a jQuery selector:

```
 $("textarea").each(function(index) {
      var id = this.id;
      myNicEditor.addInstance(this);
      $("#nic"+id).attr('contenteditable','false');
 });
```

However, when the number of total editors rises above about 200, I start to get script timeout warnings.  At 400 I have to click "continue" twice in order for it to finish.

How would I restructure this function to prevent the timeouts?

Comment: Split this up into multiple pages... 400 textareas on one pagE??

Comment: Seriously, 400 editors on SAME page???

Comment: Have you tried `.map()`?

Comment: @DevlshOne Why .map()?

Comment: `.map` still has to run through EACH textarea, essentially, it's the same thing.

Comment: Trust me you don't want solution to this problem. If you have it, you will face bigger problems. Consider changes to UI approach if you can.

Comment: My understanding of `.each()` is that it builds the array as it traverses the DOM where `.map()` pre-builds the array and then performs the callback, it could have some perf perks.

Comment: BTW, what kind of application are you building? Just curious as I worked on an app where I needed to use 8 rich text editors and I spent hours to come up with a logic to minimize the usage.

Comment: @DevlshOne i didn't done benchmark specifically on it but usually .each() is the fastest jquery's method to loop through matched set of elements. Of course, i'm not talking about for or while loop here.

Comment: Yes, 400 is indeed a possibility.
When an admin is editing the questions to a quiz that is 50 questions long and there are 8 text boxes per question (and yes, they ALL need to be rich-text) that works out to 400 of them.

Answer (score 0):

400 rich text editors on a webpage must use a ton of resources. I think your best bet is to not try to put all of these on a single page. Try to reorganize your app - maybe break it into smaller pages, or load sub-sections of the page on demand when needed.

Or you can leave the textareas as-is, then load only the one rich editor at a time on demand as you need it.

Comment: Ah, yes... launch the plugin only as the textarea gets focus and destroy it when blurred.

Comment: @DevlshOne I wouldn't even necessarily destroy it when you leave the box - once the plugin is loaded, you've pretty much done the work, so leaving it alive probably doesn't hurt anything. But that's definitely an option to try, if necessary.

Comment: Each text box isn't its own rich text editor, there's only one editor panel on the entire page, its just that each one is hooked up to that panel.  Resources (once the page is loaded) isn't actually a problem, it's NicEdit converting `<textarea>` to a `<div>` that seems to be the issue.

Also, I was doing it that way (changing to rich-text when the editor was first used) but it looks ugly, as the styling doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is doing a lot of things in selector, but the elements found are not wrapped in jQuery objects. 200 is not so big, but anyway, there are 2 things you can do:

1. Find all textareas via vanilla JavaScript call
2. Process the textareas in event queue via setTimeout

```javascript
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")
var i = 0
var func = function() {
    var el = els[i]
    myNicEditor.addInstance(el);
    $("#nic"+el.id).attr('contenteditable','false');
    i++
    setTimeout(func,0)
}
func()
```